# Why I cannot create my own custom hook in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-custom-hooks

I was trying to make my Editor a custom hook so I created 'useEditor' hook like this

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import MathEditor from './MathEditor';

  //some other imports
    
function useEditor() {
  const [editorHtml, setEditorHtml] = useState('');
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState('Write something...');
  const [mathEditorVisible, setMathEditorVisible] = useState(false);
  const [expressionEditable, setExpressionEditable] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (html) => {
    setEditorHtml(html);
  };

  //some other functions 

  const Editor = () => (
    <div>
      <ReactQuill
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={editorHtml}
        modules={modules}
        bounds='.app'
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
      {mathEditorVisible && (
        <MathEditor
          onSaveFormula={handleSaveFormula}
          setMathEditorVisible={setMathEditorVisible}
          expressionEditable={expressionEditable}
          setExpressionEditable={setExpressionEditable}
          initialLatex=''
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );

  return {
    Editor,
    handleChange
  };
}

export default useEditor;
```

But when compiling this error occurs

***  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Editor, handleChange}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. ***

Comment: How do you use `useEditor`?

Comment: This looks like it should just be a custom component `<Editor ... />` instead of a hook.

Comment: I am using it in index.js like this 


```
import Editor from './components/useEditor';
     function App() {
        return (
           <div className='app'>
               <Editor />
           </div>
        );
     }
```

It was a custom component actually but I had to change it to a custom hook because I have to use it in a bigger project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exporting `Editor`, you are exporting `useEditor`. You have to call `useEditor` to get `Editor`

```
import useEditor from './components/useEditor';
function App() {
  const { Editor } = useEditor();
  return (
    <div className='app'> <Editor /> </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When I did so, it did not work as expected, the handleChange function in the editor does not work even though I returned it in the useEffect hook!

Comment: @lighthouse: What specifically "did not work as expected"?  What was the specific expectation?  What was the test?  What was the observed result?  Why do you return that function in the first place?  Where else are you trying to use it?  The answer above demonstrates how to use a component returned from a hook, which was the problem in the original question.  If you have a new, separate problem then you are encouraged to open a new question and include a [mcve] which demonstrates that problem.

Comment: @David yes you are right thank you! And thanks to you Konrad for the answer to the main question!